# MySQL: Many writes to table intended to fail. Bad idea?

Tags: mysql, database

I am writing an app which will require many writes (up to 100's per second). I also intend to read from this table very often. However, the majority of the writes I will be making will actually fail due to duplicate key indexes. This is intended. Will the failed writes consume MySQL table resources? Is this bad practice?

Comment: I'm just interested to know why the writes will fail - can you give further details as to what you're actually trying to store ? My worry is that all of the index seeks to check the uniqueness constraint may well cause a lock that will stall the reading threads. Somethings you can get away with, but when it involves an index it's probably very bad.

Comment: sure. I am designing a content aggregator which will pull data from an ever-growing number of sources. For each record of data I will have a URL and a user_id. I don't want to have any instances of duplicate URL and user_id in any record however I do expect that there will be many instances where potential duplicates will exist. My thought was to let the natural function of indexes do this filtering work for me. But it seems I need to find another way if it will lock up the table for reading (which is also important)

Answer (score 3):

The failed writes will consume system resources as table indices need to be consulted in order to determine if constraints are violated.  As for whether or not it is bad practice -- it does seem a little unusual to intentionally throw lots of writes expected to fail, but on the other hand, the RDBMS' job is to store, organize, and retrieve data. It is faster for the database to attempt an `INSERT` that will violate a unique constraint and fail than it is to query first to find out if the key can be inserted by application code and then insert it (where you *still* need to check constraints on the RDBMS).

Comment: Will the reads on the index cause lock escalation making any scheduled readers wait until the index isn't .. I guess 'dirty' is the best word.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html The InnoDB storage & locking docs seem to suggest that lock escalation isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily an application has some business rule abstraction layer where the integrity problem is conceptually defined; if so, most developers coming after you would expect the validation to occur there. OTOH if this is a one-time utility or you'll be the only developer forever, it will work. The hack probably isn't buying any significant improvement in efficiency compared to reading an indexed field, and it's an unpleasant place to deal with error trapping and porting in general - except for you it's not an error. (Kinda like "it's not a bug it's a feature...")